# How to get a factorial of 5000 in Go

Tags: go

I would like to calculate a factorial of 5000 in Go but got 0 as a result because the result is bigger than a uint64.
However, I was able to do it in Node.js by using

```
const BigNumber = require('big-number').
```

Is there an equivalent in Go?

What I did was:

```
func RecursiveFactorial(number int) big.Int {
    if number >= 1 {
        return big.Int{(number) * RecursiveFactorial(number-1)
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, using recursion for calculating factorials is a waste of stack. A simple `for` loop is enough. If you want to practice recursion, there are better examples.

Comment: @antonof BTW, no need to use the `big-number` package in Node.js, it has built-in `BigInt` support now: `const RecursiveFactorial = n => n >= 1n? n * RecursiveFactorial(n - 1n) : 1n;`

Answer (score 8):

In Go, use the `math/big` package.

For example,

```
// OEIS: A000142: Factorial numbers: n! = 1*2*3*4*...*n.
// https://oeis.org/A000045

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func factorial(x *big.Int) *big.Int {
    n := big.NewInt(1)
    if x.Cmp(big.NewInt(0)) == 0 {
        return n
    }
    return n.Mul(x, factorial(n.Sub(x, n)))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(factorial(big.NewInt(5000)))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/53TmmygltkR

Answer (score 3):

```
func factorial(n int64) *big.Int {
    fac := new(big.Int)
    fac.MulRange(1, n)
    return fac
}
```

z.MulRange(a, b) from math/big computes the product from all int64 a to int64 b. It uses a split and recursiv algorithm (divide and conqueer). It's far more faster than school factorial algorithms. Compute 1 000 000! quickly = ~ 8.26393168833e+5565708

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [math/big](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) package. You can implement computation `recursively` or `iteratively`. Iterative in most cases will be faster and produce less garbage. On my machine iterative impl works 3.1x faster and allocates 2.9x less garbage.

```
BenchmarkIterAndRecursive/recursive-6               3000       3891062 ns/op    17181056 B/op      15003 allocs/op
BenchmarkIterAndRecursive/iterative-6              10000       1237597 ns/op      656089 B/op       5172 allocs/op
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"
    "testing"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(factorial(big.NewInt(5000)))
    fmt.Println(factorialIter(5000))
}

func TestIterWorkTheSame(t *testing.T) {
    recursive := factorial(big.NewInt(5000))
    iterative := factorialIter(5000)
    if recursive.Cmp(iterative) != 0 {
        log.Fatalf("Invalid computation, \n[%v]\n[%v]", recursive, iterative)
    }
}

func BenchmarkIterAndRecursive(b *testing.B) {
    b.Run("recursive", func(b2 *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b2.N; i++ {
            factorial(big.NewInt(5000))
        }
    })
    b.Run("iterative", func(b2 *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b2.N; i++ {
            factorialIter(5000)
        }
    })
}

func factorial(x *big.Int) *big.Int {
    n := big.NewInt(1)
    if x.Cmp(big.NewInt(0)) == 0 {
        return n
    }
    return n.Mul(x, factorial(n.Sub(x, n)))
}

func factorialIter(x int) *big.Int {
    result := big.NewInt(1)
    for i := 2; i <= x; i++ {
        result.Mul(result, big.NewInt(int64(i)))
    }

    return result
}
```